# Customized color for a specific command in Texstudio or in another editor

Tags: texstudio, editors, syntax-highlighting

I need to obtain a custom color for the text inside the `\sepfootnotes` command (which I defined as `\xnote` using `\newfootnotes{x}`), just to appear green like the one inside the `\nameref` command, but it would be better if it is possible to use a custom color.

For example, in `\xnote{firstnote}`, **firstnote** should appear in green or in another color.

Please note that with the `\sepfootnotes` command I refer to another file where all the texts of the notes are stored, e.g. `\xnote{firstnote}`  -->   `\xnotecontent{firstnote}{the text of the footnote}`.

This is for better locate the notes inside the editor, but it will be useful if it is possible to do the same with other commands, such as `\textit`, `\selectlanguage` and `\addfontfeature`.

It is possible to do it in TexStudio or in another LaTeX editor?

Comment: Was discussed at https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/discussion/907840/thread/b1f63fd6/